# Passing parameters from non-template to template function?

Tags: c++, parameters

I am having some trouble passing parameters for a template function trough a non-template function.

Let's supose I have this:

```
template <class T>
void A(Array <T> &A) {
    cout << "here";
}


void menu(Array<myType>& fooList) { // my type specified class type, created by me. 
    cout << "enter option ";
    cin >> a;

    switch {
       case 1: A(fooList); break;
    }
}
```

I hope the example is clear enough. Is this possible or not? Can I the parameters pass from a non-template function to a template function?

EDIT: - the actual code since the prototype i tried to build wasn't helpful.

domain.h

```
template <class T>
void printAll(Array <T> &DBst, Array <T> &DBas){
    for(int i=0; i<DBst.lenght; i++){
        DBst.M[i].printStudent();
        std::cout<<" ___ ";
        DBas.M[i].printAssgn();
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

controller.h

```
template <class T>
void _printAll(Array <T> &DB1, Array <T> &DB2){
    cout<<"List of students with their Assignment!"<<endl;
    printAll(DB1, DB2);
    cout<<"done!"<<endl;
}
```

menu.cpp

```
void Menu::mainMenu(Array <Student> &DBst,Array <Assignment> &DBas){
showMainMenu();
int ret = Menu::intInputHandler();

while(ret){
    switch(ret){
    case 1:studentMenu(DBst,DBas);break;
    case 2:assignmentMenu(DBst,DBas);break;
    case 3:statsMenu(DBst,DBas);break;
    case 4:_printAll(DBst,DBas);break; //// ERROR ***
    case 0:/*exit*/;break;
    default:cout<<"Wrong option selected!";break;
    }
    }

    }
```

menu.h

```
class Menu{

public:
    void showMainMenu();
    void showStudentMenu();
    void showAssignmentMenu();
    void showStatisticsMenu();
    string stringInputHandler();
    int intInputHandler();
    void mainMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
    void studentMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
    void assignmentMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
    void statsMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
```

};

***`..\Menu.cpp:90:29: error: no matching function for call to '_printAll(Array<Student>&, Array<Assignment>&)'`

Comment: What is wrong with your code as-is?

Comment: well i cant manage to pass from my function(tempalte) the parameters right in the menu function...

Comment: Can you please show us what exactly it is you can't do, with the associated error / symptoms?

Comment: this one: `..\Menu.cpp:90:29: error: no matching function for call to '_printAll(Array<Student>&, Array<Assignment>&)'`

Comment: The code in the question cannot produce that error.  Show the actual code and the actual error, otherwise how do you expect us to answer the question?

Comment: `_printAll` == `A`? If so then whats that second argument?

Comment: ok i show you the code i`l eddit soon, but i wanted to make job easier for you guys... brb to apste relevant code :)

Comment: Side note: Refrain from prefixing underscores to your variable names; prefixed underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your `_printAll(DBst,DBas);` are array of two different types; and `_printAll` can take only two arrays of same type. You need to define a function with

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void printAll(Array <T1> &DBst, Array <T2> &DBas)
```

and a corresponding _printAll

Comment: Thank a bunch, it makes sense now... this is the secound time since i started with c++ i`m using tempaltes... still need to learn a lot :)